# Написать запрос в CoreData что бы сравнить строки

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile, mobile-development

Здравствуйте! Вот изучаю CoreData. Строки записывать я научился, а вот сравнивать нет... Есть в фаиле Data сущность Entity, там строка text. Туда записано 10 строк. Есть textField. Надо сравнить строку из textField со строками из CoreData.Entity.text. Через do try я могу записать строки в массив array. Но через цикл for у меня не получается их сравнить почему-то.

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
let str2 = "test3"

for (index, item) in array.enumerated() {
    if(item as String == str2) {
        print("\(item) equals")
    }
}
```

Comment: for (index, item) in array.enumerated() {if item as String != sender {}} не работает. Ошибку выдает Cannot convert value of type 'UserData' to type 'String' in coercion

Comment: вы ж сказали, что сравниваете строки. а оказывается пытаетесь сравнить строку и UserData. Давайте вы как то определитесь и будем думать дальше. предположу, что вы хотите сначала из UserData достать какую то строку (например name)

Comment: У меня есть массив  array: [UserData] = [], куда я передаю  do { array = try context.fetch(UserData.fetchRequest())} данные сущности UserData, где есть атрибут text, который является строкой. В этом атрибуте содержится 10 строк. Вот эти 10 строк и надо сравнить со строкой из textField! Если я не правильно объяснил в первый раз, извиняюсь!

Comment: вместо item в сравнении используйте item.text

Comment: for (index, item) in array.enumerated() {if item.text == sender {loginImage.image = UIImage(named:"sadSmile.png")} else {loginImage.image = UIImage(named:"Smile.png"); bool1 = true}} Я  так пробовал. Ошибки нет, но не сравнивает строки все равно(((((((((((((((((

Comment: выведите item.text, выведите sender. сравните визуально. найдите что не так и будем думать

Comment: Странно то, что если я добавлю значение text в CoreData то он сравниваться будет, а остальные нет! То есть последнее значение сравнивается, а предыдущие нет(((((((((((((((( Я подцепил tableView к массиву и оно отображает 11 (теперь 11) строк. Последняя сравнивается. Остальные нет. Что за странный глюк...

Comment: скиньте как именно выглядят строки в консоли - то, что пришло из coredata и то, с чем сравниваете

Comment: Я решил учить FireBase. Ибо все равно надо учиться сохранять данные на отдельном сервере. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно подойти к этому куда проще.

```
let moc = managedObjectContext
let employeesFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Employee")

let firstName = "Trevor"
employeesFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName == %@", firstName)

do {
    let fetchedEmployees = try moc.executeFetchRequest(employeesFetch) as! [AAAEmployeeMO]
} catch {
    fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)")
}
```

В результате мы получим все элементы которые равны "Trevor".

Если нужно применять для поиск, то тогда лучше:

```
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", searchText)
```

Здесь мы получим все элементы которые хотя бы в одном месте слова совпадают с запросом.

Вот документация поэтому поводу: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html

Comment: Пытаюсь делать как в мануале и ошибки вылетают! Я так понимаю синтаксис изменился, а в мануале не поправили... Все та же проблема. Не могу вытащить из CoreData строки и сравнить их со строкой из textField.

Comment: Чем не подходит этот метод - let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", searchText)? Как раз вместо searchText значение из textField и вместо name указать значение в каком столбце искать

Comment: Это наверное для более раннего Swift подходит. У меня метода executeFetchRequest нету. Вместо него просто execute(NSPersistentStoreRequest) (((((((((((((((((((